# Laravel API - Dealing with an API "entity" with many associations

Tags: php, api, laravel, associations

So I have an API I am building and it has a "Member" model. I am building this API around a pre-existing database and this "Member" has close to 16 relationships in just its basic query. I am now supposed to build out my api to respond to something like `member/{id}/pension` and return all of its PENSION information. This is a whole new set of associations along with some of the associations ive already created. My questions is, is it bad practice to start creating extra Controller methods in the MembersController like showPension / showPensionSummary or should I move these out to a different controller....or is there an option c that I am missing.

Comment: Is the id the id of the member?

Comment: and yes the id is the id of the member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is bad practice to put it all in one controller. You then do not apply the single responsibility protocol (SRP). But if I'm not mistaking, you have a `Member` model. A member has a relationship with pension, so you have `Pension` model?

Within `Member` model you could add a method like:

```
public function pension() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Pension');
}
```

If you have more routes with {id} from member you can use route model binding. Change the id parameter to {member}. Then inside the AppServiceProvider add the following code:

```
$router->bind('member', 'App\Models\Member');
```

Create a folder inside your Controller folder called Member. In there add a MemberController and a PensionController. Inside the PensionController add method: showPension or just show (cause you're already in the controller). More cleaner this way.

```
public function show(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    echo json_encode($request->member->pension);
}
```

Comment: Yes but the problem becomes this. If I returned a member and all of its relationships as part of the API call it would be a ridiculously large return. There are probably about a total of 40 relationships after you take into account everything. So when someone uses the member/{id} endpoint of my api should they get back this giant json return with a members every relationship or should I somehow split up the api into multiple calls

Comment: Ah, now it's clear to me I think. Yes just use the approach mentioned above. But use in different controller. I suggest to make a folder inside your controller folder called members. Add there a MemberController and a PensionController. Use the above in the pension controller. Use route model binding for this. So the only thing left to in the controller method is: echo json_encode($request->member->pension);

Comment: Thats actually a pretty good idea. I did a similar thing with some of my models already. I'll play around with it and see how I feel about it. If you want to update your answer I'll mark it accepted unless someone else has a better idea :P

Comment: @BillGarrison I've edited my answer :) Glad it helped you!